# My own snprintf implementation in C

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, formatting

I decided to make my own version of `snprintf` in C. I intentionally changed some things though. My version guarantees the buffer printed to will be null-terminated, and it returns the number of characters printed to the buffer, not the number that would have been printed if the buffer's size was not limited. And I only worried about some of the main formatting features, like `%s`, `%c`, `%d`, `%h`, and `%H`.

I would love to know what I could do better in this and improve, or what aspects of it I did or did not implement well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int INT_TO_STR_DIGITS_L[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
int INT_TO_STR_DIGITS_U[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

int int_to_str(int x, char *buf, size_t size, int base, int uppercase) {
    int length = (int)ceil(log((double)x)/log((double)base));
    int r, i = 0;
    char c;

    if (size < length) {
        x /= (int)pow(base, (float)(length - size));
        length = size;
    }

    do {
        if (i >= size) break;
        r = x % base;
        if (uppercase) {
            c = INT_TO_STR_DIGITS_U[r];
        } else {
            c = INT_TO_STR_DIGITS_L[r];
        }
        buf[length-i-1] = c;
        x /= base;
        i++;
    } while (x != 0);

    return i;
}

int my_snprintf(char *str, size_t max_size, const char *fmt, ...) {

    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, fmt);

    int chars_printed = 0;
    char *start_str = str;

    char c, *str_arg;
    int num, len;
    int uppercase = 0, base = 10;

    for (int i = 0; fmt[i] != 0; i++) {
        if (max_size - chars_printed <= 0) {
            break;
        } else if (fmt[i] == '%') {
            i++;
            switch (fmt[i]) {
            case 'c':
                c = va_arg(arg_list, int);
                str[chars_printed++] = c;
                break;
            case '%':
                str[chars_printed++] = '%';
                break;
            case 's':
                str_arg = va_arg(arg_list, char *);
                len = strnlen(str_arg, max_size - chars_printed);
                strncpy(str+chars_printed, str_arg, len);
                chars_printed += len;
                break;
            case 'H':
                uppercase = 1;
            case 'h':
                base = 16;
            case 'd':
                num = va_arg(arg_list, int);
                len = int_to_str(num, str+chars_printed, max_size - chars_printed, base, uppercase);
                chars_printed += len;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid format.\n");
                va_end(arg_list);
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            str[chars_printed++] = fmt[i];
        }
    }

    if (chars_printed == max_size) chars_printed--;
    str[chars_printed] = 0;

    va_end(arg_list);
    return chars_printed;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Bug

Your int to string conversion isn't working correctly when the number being printed is an exact power of the base.  Here is a program that demonstrates the bug:

```
int main(void)
{
    char buf[256];

    memset(buf, 'z', 256);
    my_snprintf(buf, 256, "abc%ddef", 1000);
    printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Expected output:

```
abc1000def
```

Actual output:

```
ab1000zdef
```

As you can see, the `1000` portion was written one too far to the left.  The problem is that your number length computation is off by one for exact powers of the base.

#### Unnecessary and unsafe floating point operations

The *Floating Point Police*™ would like to point out that the use of floating point in `int_to_str()` is both unnecessary and dangerous.  First of all, this line:

```
int length = (int)ceil(log((double)x)/log((double)base));
```

could be rewritten to use a loop to count the number of digits.  By using floating point, you open yourself up to rounding errors.  For example, if `x` were 125 and `base` were 5, you would expect `length` to be 3.  However, when I ran the above code using 125 and 5 on my x86 machine, I got a `length` of 4 instead.  This is because the division evaluated to something like 3.00000001 and `ceil` rounded it up to 4.  (Of course there is already an unrelated off by one bug mentioned in the previous section.  This floating point use is a separate cause of concern).

The same thing applies to this line:

```
    x /= (int)pow(base, (float)(length - size));
```

This could be rewritten to be a loop where you divide by `base` once per loop iteration.  By using `pow()` and casting to `int`, you run the risk of the result of `pow` erroneously rounding down to the previous int.

Answer (score 4):

1. Bug: `int_to_str()` fails for negative `int`.
2. Undefined specifiers: `%h` and `%H` are not part of the standard library.  So without a specification, hard to know if they are performing correctly. Did you mean `%x` and `%X`?
3. Mixing `int` and `size_t` math.  This is pedantic point.  As the max of those 2 types are not specified to which is larger, there is a worst case chance `max_size - chars_printed <= 0` will *never* be true should `max_size > INT_MAX`.  Suggest adding the `**` line below and avoid math that relies on signed math as it is likely unsigned math.  *or* use `size_t  chars_printed` and cope with returning `int` at the end. (`chars_printed` should be of the type with the greater positive range.)

   ```
   int my_snprintf(char *str, size_t max_size, const char *fmt, ...) {
     if (max_size > INT_MAX) Handle_PathologicalCase_TBD(); // **
     int chars_printed = 0;
       ...
       // if (max_size - chars_printed <= 0) {
       if (max_size <= chars_printed) {
   ```
4. Bug `int length = (int)ceil(log((double)x)/log((double)base));` is not as reliable as hoped for.  Detailed well in another [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132889/29485).  The alternative is to convert to a string with an internal max-sized buffer like `char buf[34]` for `int32_t` in base 2.  Then copy the buffer result.
5. Style: fall through.  Cases that drop though *look* like an error without a `break`.  Add comment to show intent

   ```
       case 'H':
           uppercase = 1;
           // fall though
       case 'h':
           base = 16;
           // fall though
       case 'd':
   ```
6. `printf("Invalid format.\n");` and such are better printed to `stderr`.

   ```
   fprintf(stderr, "Invalid format.\n");
   ```
7. Wrong type for `len`

   ```
   // int len;
   size_t len;
   ```
8. Style: No need to declare `d` so soon.  Same for `c`.  Suggest type change `unsigned char c = va_arg(arg_list, int);`.  Same for `str_arg`.

   ```
   // int num;
   //  ... ~30 lines
   //    case 'd':
   //      num = va_arg(arg_list, int);

       case 'd':
           int num = va_arg(arg_list, int);
   ```
9. Minor: Code simplification

   ```
   // if (uppercase) {
   //     c = INT_TO_STR_DIGITS_U[r];
   // ...

   if (uppercase) {
       c = "0123456789ABCDEF"[r];
   } else {
       c = "0123456789abcdef"[r];
   }
   ```
10. Corner bug: Below code fails (UB).  Watch for `size == 0`

    ```
    my_snprintf(str, 0, fmt, ...)
    ```
11. [Edit] Bug: `int uppercase = 0, base = 10;` is initialized outside the `for()` loop.  So a `"%d"` after a `"%x"` will be treated as hex.  A `"%h"` after a `"%H"` will be treated as print with uppercase letters.  Simple fix, move `int uppercase = 0, base = 10;` to after `else if (fmt[i] == '%')`.  Better fix: pass base and upper/lower as parameters to new `int_to_str()`.
12. `char *start_str` unused.  Recommend deletion.
13. Variables/functions like `INT_TO_STR_DIGITS_L[]` and `int_to_str()` that are only intended for local use should be `static`.  Unclear why all uppercase.  Avoid long line that exceed presentation width

    ```
    // int INT_TO_STR_DIGITS_L[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    ```

    `static int int_to_str_digits_l[16] = "0123456789abcdef";`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am very pedantic so I appreciate number 3! I have a question though, what's the advantage of using `unsigned char` over `char` for the variable `c`?

Comment: @addison With `case 'c': c = va_arg(arg_list, int);`, using `unsigned char c = va_arg(arg_list, int);` is consistent with the C spec concerning `fprintf(... "%c" ...)`: "the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written." C11 §7.21.6.1 8.  As this code sends data to a `char *`, not likely to make much difference if `char` or `unsigned char` is used.  IAC, assigning an `int` to a `unsigned char c` is well defined. Not so sure  assigning an `int` to a signed `char` is so well defined.  Note:the argument passed is an `int`, perhaps not in `char` range.